# How can I treat a line in text as an integer?

Tags: python

I am writing a simple gambling program. The best way I can think of for changing how much money you have after a game, rather than having it default back to the starting amount, is to have a separate text file with your starting amount written out. In my 'money.txt' I just have 100.

Here is my code:

```
money = open('money.txt').read()
print(money)

win = input(" Heads or tails? ")
if win == 'heads':
    with open('money.txt', 'w') as change:
        change.write(money * 3)
```

The output in money.txt is:

```
100
100
100
```

Two questions. How can I have the result be 300? And is there a better way for me to go about this concept of saving a changing variable?

Answer (score 1):

Your money is a string and if you want to triple the amount, you need to cast it to int (or bigger range numeric type) and triple it and save it back to the file.

Always parse your money txt value to a numeric value and use it.

Comment: In Python there is no bigger range numeric type than `int`.  Also you're missing a step - you need to convert the number back to a string before writing it to the file.

Comment: Good point unless if it's Python 2.x and yes. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Python 2.x no longer officially exists, even if you might still see a lot of it about.  I've been using Python 3.x for so long that I forgot 2.x had different integer types.

Comment: True but most linux distros include Python 2.x and someone working in restricted environments might be forced to use 2.x. Just saying from personal experience.